# Asymmetric interference picture when screen is not perpendicular to wave normal

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, interference

In a physics class, we performed a double-slit experiment and observed that when you rotate the screen so that it is no longer perpendicular to the wave normal, the symmetry of the maxima breaks down. Can someone explain this?
So I can explain what did I wait actually. I tought that it would be the same thing , if we rotate the slit or rotate the screen.
[image: So here is my draft, g represents the length of the slit and alpha represents the deflection angle.]

So here are the equations that I tought;

$$ \ S1=cos(\phi) $$
$$ \ S2=cos(x)*g $$
where $\Delta s$ represents the optical path difference.So ;
$$\Delta S = S2-S1 =(sin(\alpha+\phi)-sin(\phi))*g$$
because we know that $$ x= 90-(\alpha-\phi)$$
and $$S2=sin(\alpha+\phi)*g$$
For the Interference Maximums we know the equation ;
$$\Delta S=k*\lambda$$
So ;
$$k*\lambda=(sin(\alpha+\phi)-sin(\phi))*g$$
We are trying to find alpha , and alpha is 
$$\alpha=arcsin(sin(\phi)+(k*\lambda)/g)-\phi$$
if i did not make a silly mistake. So I would expect that the distance between the maximums increases, because the deflection angle increases when the rotation angle $\phi$ increases.
(I apoligize , because I saw the answers too late and I can edit my question now)

Comment: Because the problem is no longer symmetric - what were you expecting? What is your real question here?